# Unsafe auto-fill of structs in .Net, for Network code

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

The idea: Being able to take the bytes of any struct, send those bytes across a TcpClient (or through my Client wrapper), then have the receiving client load those bytes and use pointers to "paint" them onto a new struct.

The problem: It reads the bytes into the buffer perfectly; it reads the array of bytes on the other end perfectly. The "paint" operation, however, fails miserably. I write a new Vector3(1F, 2F, 3F); I read a Vector3(0F, 0F, 0F)...Obviously, not ideal.

Unfortunately, I don't see the bug - If it works one way, it should work the reverse - And the values are being filled in.

The write/read functions are as follows:

```
    public static unsafe void Write<T>(Client client, T value) where T : struct
    {
        int n = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(value);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[n];
        {
            var handle = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(value, System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType.Pinned);
            void* ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();
            byte* bptr = (byte*)ptr;

            for (int t = 0; t < n; ++t)
            {
                buffer[t] = *(bptr + t);
            }
            handle.Free();
        }

        client.Writer.Write(buffer);
    }
```

*Line Break*

```
    public static unsafe T Read<T>(Client client) where T : struct
    {
        T r = new T();
        int n = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(r);
        {
            byte[] buffer = client.Reader.ReadBytes(n);
            var handle = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(r, System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType.Pinned);
            void* ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();
            byte* bptr = (byte*)ptr;

            for (int t = 0; t < n; ++t)
            {
                *(bptr + t) = buffer[t];
            }
            handle.Free();
        }
        return r;
    }
```

Help, please, thanks.

Edit:

Well, one major problem is that I'm getting a handle to a temporary copy created when I passed in the struct value.

Edit2:

Changing "T r = new T();" to "object r = new T();" and "return r" to "return (T)r" boxes and unboxes the struct and, in the meantime, makes it a reference, so the pointer actually points to it.

However, it is slow. I'm getting 13,500 - 14,500 write/reads per second.

Edit3:

OTOH, serializing/deserializing the Vector3 through a BinaryFormatter gets about 750 writes/reads per second. So a *Lot* faster than what I was using. :)

Edit4:

Sending the floats individually got 8,400 RW/second. Suddenly, I feel much better about this. :)

Edit5:

Tested GCHandle allocation pinning and freeing; 28,000,000 ops per second (Compared to about 1,000,000,000 Int32/int add+assign/second. So compared to integers, it's 35 times slower. However, that's still comparatively fast enough). Note that you don't appear to be able to pin classes, even if GCHandle does auto-boxed structs fine (GCHandle accepts values of type "object").

Now, if the C# guys update constraints to the point where the pointer allocation recognizes that "T" is a struct, I could just assign directly to a pointer, which is...Yep, incredibly fast.

<s>Next up: Probably testing write/read using separate threads. :) See how much the GCHandle actually affects the send/receive delay.</s>

As it turns out:

Edit6:

```
        double start = Timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        for (t = 0; t < count; ++t)
        {
            Vector3 from = new Vector3(1F, 2F, 3F);
            // Vector3* ptr = &test;
            // Vector3* ptr2 = &from;
            int n = sizeof(Vector3);
            if (n / 4 * 4 != n)
            {
                // This gets 9,000,000 ops/second;
                byte* bptr1 = (byte*)&test;
                byte* bptr2 = (byte*)&from;
                // int n = 12;
                for (int t2 = 0; t2 < n; ++t2)
                {
                    *(bptr1 + t2) = *(bptr2 + t2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // This speedup gets 24,000,000 ops/second.
                int n2 = n / 4;
                int* iptr1 = (int*)&test;
                int* iptr2 = (int*)&from;
                // int n = 12;
                for (int t2 = 0; t2 < n2; ++t2)
                {
                    *(iptr1 + t2) = *(iptr2 + t2);
                }
            }
        }
```

So, overall, I don't think the GCHandle is really slowing things down. (Those who are thinking this is a slow way of assigning one Vector3 to another, remember that the purpose is to serialize structs into a byte[] buffer to send over a network. And, while that's not what we're doing here, it would be rather easy to do with the first method).

Edit7:

The following got 6,900,000 ops/second:

```
        for (t = 0; t < count; ++t)
        {
            Vector3 from = new Vector3(1F, 2F, 3F);
            int n = sizeof(Vector3);
            byte* bptr2 = (byte*)&from;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[n];
            for (int t2 = 0; t2 < n; ++t2)
            {
                buffer[t2] = *(bptr2 + t2);
            }
        }
```

...Help! I've got IntruigingPuzzlitus! :D

Comment: This isn't worth doing.  The cost of pinning the struct will outweigh the performance benefits.  However, do not believe me until you measure.

Comment: For future reference, is there a way to get this sort of functionality for structs without a high performance cost?

Comment: I don't know.  Note that I'm not sure whether pinning _value types_ is also slow.  (reference types are)

Comment: Structs aren't any faster to pin.

Comment: Note that `new T()` uses reflection (believe it or not) and might also be slow.

Comment: Any suggestions on avoiding that?

Comment: Why don't you just use normal serialization. For example using protobuf? Raw copy of structs isn't a good way to serialize data.

Comment: Read Edit2 and Edit3 for a speed comparison of serializing using this method and serializing through a BinaryFormatter.